# Creating a logical variable that identifies whether a string variable occurs within another string

Tags: r

I have a quick question about `grep` that I can't seem to resolve. Let's say that I have a list of names: `brand<-c(Brand1, Brand2, Brand3, Brand4)`.  I'd like to identify whether or not any of these names occur within another string variable (var1), and then create a logical variable (T/F).

```
ID        var1                    var_filter
1         Text about Brand 1      TRUE
1         Text                    FALSE
1         Text about Brand 2      TRUE
1         Text about Brand 3      TRUE
1         Text                    FALSE
1         Text about Brand 1      TRUE
```

How would I go about doing this? My guess is `grep`, but I'm not sure how to do it when I have an entire list of possible strings instead of a single string.

Comment: possibly `sapply(brand, function(x) grepl(x,var1[k]))` where you'd loop over the `k` rows in your dataframe.  `grepl` returns logical rather than length or location, so better fitted to your need.  The output of this `sapply` will be a list of TRUE, FALSE, so you would have to condense it one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of `sapply`, `grepl`, and `any` to accomplish the task.  The idea is to use grepl to find which elements in the text contain any given brand.  I use sapply to do these for each of the brands.  Then we use `apply` with `any` to identify which values in the text contained any of the brands.

```
brands <- c("CatJuice", "robopuppy", "DasonCo")

text <- c("nononono", "That CatJuice is great", "blargcats", "I gave the robopuppy some CatJuice")

id <- sapply(brands, grepl, text, fixed = TRUE)
# if case sensitivity is an issue
#id <- sapply(tolower(brands), grepl, tolower(text), fixed = TRUE)
apply(id, 1, any)
```

This is case sensitive so if that is an issue you could easily use `tolower` to convert everything to lower case.

Comment: To clarify, if I use `tolower` do I need to compare text against two lists of strings? P.S. I love your examples!

Answer (score 1):

```
Brand1 <- "Brand 1";  Brand2 <- "Brand 2"; Brand3 <- "Brand 3"; Brand4 <- "Brand 3"
brand <- c(Brand1, Brand2, Brand3, Brand4)

dfrm$var_filter <- grepl( paste(brand, collapse="|"), dfrm$var1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `|` in patters. Like this:

```
dados <- read.table(text='ID var1
1 TextaboutBrand1
1 Text
1 TextaboutBrand2
1 TextaboutBrand3
1 Text
1 TextaboutBrand1', header=TRUE, sep=' ')

grep1 <- function(x, brand) { length(grep(paste0(brand,collapse='|'), x[2])) == 1 }

apply(dados,1,grep1,brand)
```

Or use `mapply()`...

Comment: Naming a function `grep1` when there is a function `grepl` seems unwise. That is especially the case here when, the `grepl` function would seem more appropriate anyway. I did like the idea of using paste(..., collapse="|").

Comment: @DWin I'm new in regex world, didn't know the `grepl()` function.